# Check interrupted status from within wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

When a thread `t` calls the `wait()` method on an object `u`, it goes to the WAITING state until another thread calls `notify()` on the same object `u` **OR** another thread calls the `interrupt()` method on the waiting thread `t`. Taking into account that a waiting thread does not consume CPU cycles, how is it possible for the waiting thread to check the *interrupted status* within `wait()` and throw an `InterruptedException`?

That is, I imagine the following code within `wait()`:

```
if (Thread.interrupted())  // Clears interrupted status!
  throw new InterruptedException();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A thread in the status WAITING must be resumed to become RUNNABLE again.

This resumption is being done at a lower level and is invoked by both, a notification or an interrupt.

A waiting thread does not execute any code. Instead the interrupt flag is set (at a lower level), the thread is resumed - state RUNNABLE - and once it is RUNNING again, the interrupt status is checked.